# How do I re-ask a question for a new release?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, answered-questions

The accepted answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22054/how-can-i-suspend-using-a-keyboard-shortcut-without-administrator-privileges) stopped working when I upgraded to 11.04. What is the preferred way to ask for updated answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you know how to do it in the newer version:

- update the accepted answer by adding the new information

If you don't know the answer, there is no harm in asking another question, but:

- at the very least, link the two questions afterwards. Better yet, merge them into one.

Merging should be done by updating the older question, unless you have a very good reason to extend the newer one (i.e. the old one is of very poor quality).

When you're done merging, mark the new question as a duplicate of the old one, after adding the newer version tag to the old question, or flag it for moderator attention.

- Right from the start, make sure to state your intentions in an aside or a comment:

  > This question [has been asked](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1345/) for version 10.10.

If the question is quite prominent, or not that difficult, it will in many cases suffice to just add a comment to the accepted answer, "this doesn't work in Natty, can you update your answer?", which is what you should always try first.

Comment: Goddammit, I've been posting bounties for this exact reason this whole time :P